# Class Session PHP

Tags: php, class, session

I have a class to generate the session_id, but every f5 it was renewed.

How do I get it not to renew every f5?

```
<?php

class SessionIdSaf
{
    function sessionGenerate() {

      $httponly = true;
      $session_hash = 'sha512';
      if (in_array($session_hash, hash_algos())) {
        ini_set('session.hash_function', $session_hash);
      }
      ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);
      ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

      $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
      session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], md5('secure'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), $httponly);
      session_name(md5('secure'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
      session_start();
      return session_id();

  }

  function sessionRegenerate() {

    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
    return session_id();

  }

}


session_start();
if (session_id()) {
    $sessionIdSaf           = new SessionIdSaf();
    $sessionIdSafGenerate   = $sessionIdSaf->sessionGenerate();
}
echo $sessionIdSafGenerate;
```

I want a simple class to generate the session_id and regenerate.

Just to generate a session_id for all site visitors.

Comment: FYI: `md5(0,3)` does not do anything useful.

Comment: thanks! I made the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `session_regenerate_id(true);` every time, therefore the session id is regenerating every time this function is called.

Comment: Thank you!! The way I did the class is a good practice? You would have an example to show me?

Comment: It would be quite hard to give you an good concrete example, I suggest you browse the web for some best practices! Good luck!